# Having problems uploading an image to Parse using cordova's camera.getPicture

Tags: cordova, parse-platform

I'm trying to save an image to Parse after capturing it with Cordova's camera.getPicture method.

Here's the sample code running this:

```
// onclick event to take a picture
<button onclick="capturePhoto();"></button>

// function implementation
function capturePhoto() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}

// Success callback
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var parseFile = new Parse.File("myPic.jpg", {base64:imageData});
    parseFile.save().then(function() {
        // The file has been saved to Parse.                
    }, function(error) {
        // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });
}
```

If I simply set a string as shown in the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#files) for JavaScript it works.

```
var base64 = "V29ya2luZyBhdCBQYXJzZSBpcyBncmVhdCE=";
var file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", { base64: base64 });
```

Could someone pls point me in the right direction or give an alternate implementation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to prepend some file information to `imageData` before sending it off:

```
var base64pic = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
var parseFile = new Parse.File("myPic.jpg", {base64:base64pic});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST api to upload file from cordova app.

In your controller :

```
var cameraOptions = {
    destinationType: 0, // base64
    encodingType: 0 
};

$scope.takePicture = function() {
    cameraOptions.sourceType = 1;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
}

$scope.selectPicture = function() {
    cameraOptions.sourceType = 0;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, cameraOptions);
}

function onSuccess(picture) {

    File.upload(picture)
        .success(function(data) {
            // upload finish
        });

    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.preview = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + picture;
    });
}

function onFail(resp) {
    alert('Error: ' + resp);
}
```

In File service :

```
angular.factory('File', function ($http) {
    return {
        upload: function (photo) {

            var json = {
                'base64': photo,
                '_ContentType': 'image/jpeg'
            }

            var config = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/pict.jpg',
                data: json,
                headers: {
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'XXXXX',
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'XXXXX'
                }
            };

            return $http(config);
        }
    }
});
```